# definite integral on half-closed interval

Tags: calculus

When $f$ is continuous on $[a,b)$, the definite integral of f is

$$
\int_a^b f(x) dx.
$$

When $g$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, the definite integral of g is

$$
\int_a^b g(x) dx
$$

How can you explain the difference between those two?  (as advanced calculus or analysis maybe)

Thanks for reading it.

Comment: What kind of integrals are these, and what happens to $f$ at $b$? If these are Riemann integrals, then the first one could be an *improper integral* (e.g., $\int_0^1\frac{1}{(x-1)^2}\,dx$, or $\int_0^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-1}}\,dx$, one of which exists and one of which does not).

Comment: It should be instructive to have a look at the very definition of the (Riemann) integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $f$ continuous on $[a,b]$ There is no difference between $\int_{[a,b]} f dx$ and $\int_{[a,b)} f dx$ with respect to the usual Lebesgue measure, since a single point is a set of measure zero.

Here is an intuitive way to look at this:  The area under **a single point** is zero, since the rectangle will have no width.  Because of this, it does not matter if we add that point in or not, so both integrals are the same.

**Remark:** As pointed out by Arturo in the above comments, we have to be careful when dealing with the improper Riemann integral.  (Which is defined to be a limit of Riemann integrals.)